# JQuery maximum .load calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the `LiquidSlider` [framework](http://kevinbatdorf.github.io/liquidslider/) and in each tab there is lots of HTML. So I decided to put the HTML into separate `.html` files to make the main page `index.html` cleaner.

Here is my HTML:

```
..
<head>
    .. <-- Import jquery, slider files, etc -->

    <!-- Import HTML from other files into divs -->
    <script>
      $(function(){
        $("#about-content").load("about.html");
        $("#other-content").load("other.html");
        $("#help-content").load("help.html");
        $("#contact-content").load("contact.html");
      });
  </script> 
</head>
<body>
  <section id="navigation">
    ..
  </section>

  <div class="liquid-slider" id="main-slider">
    <!-- About -->
    <div>
      <h2 class="title">about</h2>
      <div id="about-content"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Other -->
    <div>
      <h2 class="title">other</h2>
      <div id="other-content"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Help -->
    <div>
      <h2 class="title">help</h2>
      <div id="help-content"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Contact -->
    <div>
      <h2 class="title">contact</h2>
      <div id="contact-content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section id="footer">
    ..
  </section>
</body>
..
```

So when the document is loaded, theoretically the HTML would be loaded in via the `.load` calls right? It seems to work fine, until it gets to the very last tab (`contact`), where it just fails to load any content..

Odd right? I tried moving the `divs` around to see if it was a problem with my `html` files, but the last element **always** fails to load. Then I tried adding another tab, and the **last two** fail to load. This leads me to believe there is an upper-limit to the number of `.load` calls, capped at 3?

Anyone have any ideas or see any obvious problems? Or even suggest any *better* ways of achieving the same thing?

Thanks.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining how what you describe might be possible -- there is certainly no built-in cap on `load`. This is something you have to debug using some kind of HTTP inspector (browser's built in dev tools should be adequate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RTM](http://api.jquery.com/load), there's nothing there about a max number of calls, but there's a lot of information (and examples) of what kinds of callbacks you can use, which might just help you to diagnose the problem itself, for example:

```
$("#contact-content").load("contact.html", function( response, status, xhr )
{
    if ( status == "error" )
    {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        console.log(xhr);//<-- check this
        $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
    }
});
```

As an alternative, just go for the old-school `$.get` call, since you don't seem to be passing any data to the server:

```
$.get( "contact.html", function( data )
{
    $("#contact-content").html(data);
});
```

Another thing to consider might be: given that you're using liquidSlider, I take it not all of the content is visible from the off. Why not register a click handler, that `.load`'s that content when the user actually clicks something? That does away with that series of load calls... Perhaps it's a concurrency issue of sorts. By that I mean: [browsers restrict the number of concurrent AJAX requests that can be made](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network).Perhaps you're running into that restriction, and have to wait for the requests to be completed? It's a long shot, but you never know... If you want to, [check your browser here](http://www.browserscope.org/alltests)

But either way, using JS to fetch parts of the content dynamically is all well and good, but remember that I can switch off JS support in my browser. Or that, if your JS contains a syntax error, the script execution grinds to a halt, leaving me with a (half) empty page to gaze at.
Just using *any* server-side scripting language seems to me to be a better fit:

```
//index.php -- using PHP as an example
<div id="contact-content"><?php include 'contact.html'; ?></div>
```

After this gets processed by PHP, the response from the server will be a fully-fledged html page, that doesn't require any JS-on-the-fly loading. It'll almost certainly perform better, and still allows for cleaner html code on your server...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I still haven't managed to get it working, but have found some very interesting results. I will also modify my code to utilise server-side scripting later down the track!

Comment: @Ubobo: When choosing your server-side language, look at your options. For now, all you seem to be needing is a templating language. PHP is easy, and is more than capable to do what you need. But if there is a chance that you're going to end up with a dynamic site, look into frameworks or other options. Be it PHP frameworks or FW's in other languages. Django (Python) is quite popular these days, as is Rails (Ruby). Just _look_ at these languages, and see which syntax feels most comfortable. I've tried python, nice but in spite of promises made by others, haven't learned to love the syntax...

Answer (score 0):

Server Side Includes would seem to me to be a better way of achieving the same thing.  Use the right tool for the right job and all that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var array = ['about', 'other', 'contact', 'help'];
for (i in array)                               
    {

    $('#'+array[i]).load(array[i]+'.html', function(){ });
    }
</script>
```